# Code stuck when the response of an async request is 404 status code

Tags: c#, http, asynchronous, async-await

My code is getting stuck on `GetAsync().Result`. The `GetAsync()` method is the following:

I am calling an API endpoint asynchronously like this:

```
public async Task<List<Account>> GetAsync(string feature, string licenseType, string token)
{
   // Find accounts that have a license for the user
   var accounts = await _licenseMgr.GetAccountsAsync(
      feature,
      licenseType,
      token);

   return accounts;
}
```

After the awaited method is ran, the code simply gets stuck. When checking with Fiddler, it appears that the response header is `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found`.

Why is the code getting stuck there instead of, at least, returning null or something?

Comment: Could you please show the `_licenseMgr` internals? Most likely problem is somewhere there.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "stuck"? Do you happen to swallow exceptions anywhere? ( Unawaited Task? Empty `catch`? `async void`? )

Comment: @Serg the _licenseMgr internals are from a NuGet and I do not have access to it

Comment: @Fildor even when inside a try-catch, the code does not even proceed to the catch

Comment: I found out that the problem is happening on `.Result`. I updated the original post, sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: @Quest, can you avoid using `Result/GetReult/Wait()` and other blocking things in the async code? The best way to solve the hang will be to replace `GetAsync().Result` with `await GetAsync()`.

Comment: Most likely the problem is that the `GetAsync` wants to continue execution after `GetAccountsAsync` finished on the thread, which is blocked with the `Result` call. And at the same time the blocked thread wants to get result of `GetAsync` to unlock. Thus, we have classical deadlock here.

Comment: Alright, it's clear what the problem is now. Thank you, @Serg! One problem I've encountered is that I can not `await GetAsync()` because the method I'm calling it is not `async`. Is there any other way to accomplish this?

Comment: => https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: @Quest Can you make your calling method `async` then? That's the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the problem is that the `GetAsync` wants to continue execution after `GetAccountsAsync` finished on the thread, which is blocked with the `Result` call. And at the same time the blocked thread wants to get result of `GetAsync` to unlock. Thus, we have classical deadlock here.

The correct solution here will be to avoid using `Result/GetReult/Wait()` and other blocking things in the async code. The best way to solve the hang will be to replace `GetAsync().Result` with `await GetAsync()`.

If such a replacement is hard to implement, you can try to forcefully put the task on the thread pool (and thus drop a current synchronization context)

```
var result = Task.Run(async () => await GetAsync()).Result;
```

(this one will or will not work depending on your environment)

The other way is to completely switch to the synchronous API everywhere.

Comment: Even with `ConfigureAwait(false)`, it still gets stuck on the `.Result` row

Comment: `var result = Task.Run(async () => await GetAsync()).Result;` worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I was wrong here - `ConfigureAwait(false).Result` does not change anything it this case. But other solution may sstill work.

Comment: I'm not sure why this would work. I think the real cause is bug in GetAccountsAsync.